# Install GPIO ports drivers for 12.04 on 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, drivers, compatibility

I bought an embedded, fanless PC for work, which should run on Ubuntu 14.04. This PC has  some direct GPIO ports as well, which came with a driver distributed from the OEM. But the driver is only compatible with 12.04.

Can anybody help me, how to convert it, so it will be compatible with 14.04?

Comment: Is it a binary driver, or do you have the source for it?

Comment: I got the source. Can i upload somehow zip files so i can show you?

Comment: Not here, but you could upload it somewhere, and we can download it (just post a link by editing the question)

Comment: Did it link above, i hope this is ok

Comment: Will take a look in a couple of hours, but it looks like it could work :)

Comment: o.O That would be great, if you do so, can you pls explain a little bit how you did it? :) That would be great!

Comment: Of course, I will add it in an answer, if I manage to compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver uses the `asm/system.h` header, which was removed from the kernel in version 3.4. So it will not compile *as is* with newer kernels. However after changing this header file, I managed to compile it.

#### Before you start

You will need to install the necessary build tools for the later steps:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

#### Modifying the `mxe5400_wdt.c` file

You need the change only line 47 in `/drvsrc/mxe5400_wdt.c`

**BEFORE:** `#include <asm/system.h>`

**AFTER:** `#include <asm/switch_to.h>`

#### The original readme file

The package contains a Readme file, which tells you what you need:

```
1.Close Ubuntu WatchDog
    (1). cd /drvsrc
    (2). cp -f mei.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
    (3). Restart
2.Install driver
    (1). cd /drvsrc
    (2). insmod ./mxe5400_wdt.ko
3.Install dll
    (1). cd /Lib
    (2). cp -f libadlmxewdt.so /usr/lib
```

However it needs some changes, as we will recompile the source.

#### Necessary changes

The driver installation part looks like this:

```
cd /drvsrc
make clean
make
insmod ./mxe5400_wdt.ko
```

The shared object file installation looks like this:

```
cd /lib_src
make clean
make
sudo cp -f libadlmxewdt.so /usr/lib
```

Comment: Thank you very much, didnt check it now but could it be that you mixed this up?BEFORE: #include <asm/switch_to.h>
AFTER: #include <asm/system.h> Shouldnt it be the other way around?

Comment: Correct, I missed that one :)

Comment: Okay it compiles i guess :) But trying to insmod this error appears: "ERROR: could not insert module ./mxe5400_wdt.ko: Device or resource busy" :(

Comment: Did you do the steps in "Close Ubuntu WatchDog"?

Comment: Yes i did it :)

Comment: Well, then there is nothing more that I could do, you could try asking another question about that specific error if you want.

Comment: [   67.557597] mxe5400_wdt: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
I found this and then the maybe correct answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin :( so it seems i really got a problem now

Comment: You could check this out: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/module-signing.txt